# MS Access 2010 - FIRST function in Access what is it in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2010

I am running a script in SQL server from MS Access and not getting the correct results due to FIRST function in MS Access

```
Select ClientID, ClientREF, FIRST(AgentID) AS FirstOFAgentID, FIRST(AgentREF) AS FirstOFAgentREF
From table 1
Right join table2 ON table1 = table2
Left join table 4 ON table1 = table4
Group by ClientID, ClienREF, AgentID, AgentREF
```

Comment: Your data is in a sql server and these are linked tables in Access where this SQL is running? Is that right? What does "Not the correct results" mean here. Can you share some sample data and desired results?

Comment: Yes in Access these are linked so basically I want to know in SQL what is the FIRST function?

Comment: Your query isn't erroring out so I suspect it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. I suspect that the issue is not `First()`, but rather a SQL query that isn't designed to get the result set that you are actually looking for. In tsql this function is `First_Value()`, but I doubt that will work here since you are in Access.

Comment: Now the SQL query is giving a 'FIRST_VALUE' must have an OVER clause, I applied FIRST_Value

Comment: To get the syntax and usage correct you should consult the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Why are you aggregating columns with `FIRST` that are also specified in `GROUP BY`? Try excluding *AgentID* and *AgentREF* in `GROUP BY` to truly get `FIRST`.

Comment: It worked :) thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense.  You have `FIRST(AgentID)`, but are including `AgentId` in the `GROUP BY`.  You query is equivalent to simply `SELECT DISTINCT` with your columns.

Presuming you really want a first value, I can readily think of in SQL Server, both using window functions.  I prefer conditional aggregation:

```
select ClientID, ClientREF,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then AgentID end) AS FirstOFAgentID, F      
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then AgentREF end) AS FirstOFAgentREF
from (select ClientID, ClientREF, AgentID, AgentREF,
             row_number() over (partition by ClientID, ClientREF order by ?) as seqnum
      from table 1 Right join
           table2
           ON table1 = table2 Left join
           table 4
           ON table1 = table4
     ) cc   
group by ClientID, ClienREF;
```

The second uses `SELECT DISTINCT` with `FIRST_VALUE()`, which is provided as a window function but not an aggregation function.